# Unable to receive incoming call when app is not in background in iOS by using Twilio sdk

Tags: ios, objective-c, twilio

I have done all the settings in my application to receive voip call by using Twilio sdk. 
I have added the voip and audio in info.plist key UIBackgroundModes

```
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
    <string>audio</string> 
    <string>voip</string> 
</array>
```

According to twilio's documentation "When TCDevice is initialized with incoming connection capability, the Twilio Client iOS SDK uses setKeepAliveTimeout:handler: to maintain its registration to Twilio's servers. You are therefore unable to use setKeepAliveTimeout:handler: in your application code as this would interfere with the SDK's background behavior."

I think this is happening because there no connection between iOS application and twilio when the app is not running in background or it is force fully removed from background.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Using `Local PushNotification` and handle it when receive this event.

Comment: Haven't receive any event from twilio if app is quit.

Comment: If your app don't running on background. It can run when user receive a remote notification. And i'm not sure your app will receive a remote notification immediate.

Comment: @Shubham : solution is that, you can sent voip push. Voip push is deliver instant. When are you get voip push ,you can start twilio client and you may receive twilio call.

Comment: @Shubham I had implemented in my project